# Add yes/no confirmation in python 3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that allows a user the ability to add data via input. I would like to add a confirmation step that will allow them to answer yes or no to continue. If they select no it should allow them to restart the function of adding data to the list. I also want to make sure they answer with Y, YES, y, yes, N, NO, n, no.  What would be the best way to accomplish this?  I've tried several solution I've found online but I end up not being able to get out of the loop of asking yes or no.  Thanks in advance.

```
def item_list():  # Create a list 
    items = []
    item_int = 0
    while 1:
        item_int += 1
        item = input("\nEnter item %d or Press Enter: " % item_int)
        if item == "":
            break
        items.append(item)
    return items


items = item_list()
print(items)
```

Comment: It is not clear to me when you want to ask for confirmation and what exactly should happen if the answer is no.

Comment: The def item_list(): allows you to put data into a list. I then want to print it and ask for confirmation if the script should continue. I later on use that list for something else. If they say yes then the script should continue if they say no it should restart the process of getting info to put into the list.

Comment: That is the same you already said. But I do not know when you want to ask for confirmation and what exactly "restart the process" mean.

Comment: @Goyo when I print it would allow the user to check for mistakes. If they select yes then it means the list is correct and should continue. If no is selected then it should allow ask for input and redo the list.

Comment: Just break the loop when the answer is yes.

Comment: this is quite a useful question, wonder why it was closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a wrapper function which calls your other function. In the wrapper function, use another loop to confirm items.

```
# wrapper function
def item_list_wrapper():
    while True:
        # call your function at the start of each iteration
        final_items = item_list()

        # confirm with the user
        print('\nThese are your items:', ', '.join(final_items))
        user_input = input('Confirm? [Y/N] ')
      
        # input validation  
        if user_input.lower() in ('y', 'yes'):
           break
        elif user_input.lower() in ('n', 'no'):  # using this elif for readability
           continue
        else:
           # ... error handling ...
           print(f'Error: Input {user_input} unrecognised.')
           break

    return final_items

# your original function
def item_list():
    items = []
    item_int = 0

    while 1:
        item_int += 1
        item = input("\nEnter item %d or Press Enter: " % item_int)
        if item == "":
            break
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Then call it as you'd normally call it.

```
items = item_list_wrapper()
print(items)
```

In the `item_list_wrapper` function, note that the line with `items = item_list()` will renew the list every time. If you want the user to continue adding existing items, you could switch the order of commands around.

```
def item_list_wrapper():

    final_items = item_list()  # call the function at the start

    while True:
        # confirm with the user
        print('\nThese are your items:', ', '.join(final_items))
        user_input = input('Confirm? [Y/N] ')

        # input validation
        if user_input.lower() in ('y', 'yes'):
           break
        elif user_input.lower() not in ('n', 'no'):
           # ... error handling ...
           print(f'Error: Input {user_input} unrecognised.')
           break

        # call your function at the start of each iteration
        new_items = item_list()

        # add new items to previous items
        final_items += new_items

    return final_items
```

Comment: `items = impl_item_list()` does nothing and returns `None`. If you wanted to illustrate this then you should at least include the `return` value. In any case, it makes the code _more_ complex, rather than easier to follow.

Comment: Now the edit to `def impl_item_list():` returns an empty list. I don't get the point of that function at all. `# ... code omitted for brevity ...` when the function needn't exist at all

Comment: @roganjosh Err... I've added a `# ... code omitted for brevity ...` comment.

Comment: And what use is that? I don't see a point for the function existing in the first place.

Comment: @roganjosh  if you insist. It's the function given by the OP.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate the edit and I misread slightly because this is actually a really convoluted way to achieve this. There is no reason to use a wrapper that I can see

Comment: @roganjosh Untested, so loads of edits. Apologies on my part. :-) How would you do it though? Recursion? Or integrating yes/no checks into OP's input parsing? I figured since I was thinking about another while-loop, so then a "wrapper" function around the first one.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS I appreciate you making that edit and added my code back.  I'll add it and test it.

Comment: @roganjosh What would you suggest if yo believe this method is convoluted?

Comment: You've thought too deeply or I miread the question: https://pastebin.com/yyXPJjkh

Comment: @roganjosh your solution is very simple however I would like to print out what has been added to list and if they made a mistake by selecting no it should allow them to start over with the list.

Comment: @JHCTac That is already printed just one line above.

Answer (score 16):

```
answer = input("Continue?")
if answer.lower() in ["y","yes"]:
     # Do stuff
else if answer.lower() in ["n","no"]:
     # Do other stuff
else:
     # Handle "wrong" input
```

Comment: `if answer.lower()[0] == 'y'` and so on

Comment: @roganjosh It depends on the application. What if you wanted to write `Yellow`?

Comment: Fair point, but you'd be using completely the wrong application. If you want to _enforce_ a "yes" or "no" answer, you can still remove all the case variations you can think of.

Answer (score 3):

My answer would be extension of @B. Plüster but it allows slightly bigger range of the inputs and prevent rejections of case-sensitive typos:

```
answer = input("Continue?")
if answer.upper() in ["Y", "YES"]:
    # Do action you need
else if answer.upper() in ["N", "NO"]:
    # Do action you need
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't know whether this is efficient enough.

```
    items = list()
    tr = [" Y", "YES", "y", "yes"]
    fs = ["N", "NO", "n", "no"]
    item_int = 0
    def item_list():  # Create a list
        global  item_int
        global items
        response = input("\nDo you want to enter data: ")
        if response == "":
            return
        if response in tr:
            item_int += 1
            item = input("\nEnter item %d or Press Enter: " % item_int)
            items.append(item)
        elif response in fs:
            item_int=0
            print("List cleared!")
            items.clear()
        item_list()
    item_list()
    print(items)
```

Comment: There is no reason to decalre anything `global` here and that can cause all sorts of issues

Comment: If not it throws "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'item_int' referenced before assignment"

Comment: It will do, because you started with an anti-pattern in Python. You should read about "scope". Making something work on the back of bad practice is not something that should be spread